# Objective-C. Math functions

Tags: objective-c, math

I have a variable which contain the textfield value. I want to multiply that x value with a decimal number like 0.013. But after multiplication I got as answer 0.
It takes the decimal value as 0. What is the reason?

Comment: "Can you help me debug my code, which I won't show you?"

Comment: float x=[xtxt.text floatValue];float x2=x*0.013; textfield.text=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.2f",x2];

Comment: float x=[xtxt.text floatValue];//suppose it's 3.0
    float y=0.013;
    NSLog(@"number:%f",x*y);// it will give the output:0.039000

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In a comment, the OP notes

> If i use 4/3 then it only takes answer as 1

This suggests that the problem is in how the value is initialized: `4/3` is [integer division](http://www.drpaulcarter.com/cs/common-c-errors.php#2.5), returning the `int` value `1`. The solution is to be sure that the calculations are actually dealing with floats, start to finish, by using float literals, e.g., replacing `4/3` with `4.0/3.0`

Answer (score 1):

Once you get the text from the textfield, convert the string using `floatValue` :

```
CGFloat val = [myValue floatValue];
CGFloat res = val * 0.013;
```

Comment: it will not take the decimal value

Answer (score 0):

you need to convert the text to the required format:

```
float floatValue = [yourTextField floatValue];
int intValue = [yourTextField intValuew];
```

Comment: If i use 4/3 then it only takes answer as 1. If i use double,float anything,answer is rounded.

Comment: I do not understand. How can Xcode round a float without telling it to? Please edit your answer with your full code so we can spot the issue.